# Retrieving data from AJAX function for another outside function

Tags: ajax

I need to get a new file name using an ajax call so I can use it in another function.  This is the original call for the new filename I am trying to retrieve from the setup_file function.  The file array has all the data I need including the original file name.

```
var newfilename = setup_file(file);
```

But when I try to return the data I need from said function, it doesn't work.

```
function setup_file(file) {

var newfilename;

  var newtitle = jQuery("#choosetitle").val();
  var aspect = jQuery("#chooseaspect").val();
  var uploadlanguage = jQuery("#uploadlanguage").val();


  jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',

        type : 'POST',
        async: false,
        datatype : 'JSON',
        data : {action : 'process_uploads',fileinfo: file,filetitle : newtitle, aspect : aspect, uploadlanguage : uploadlanguage},
        success : function(data){

            var json = JSON.parse(data);
            var newfilename = json['filename'];

alert(newfilename);
//this alerts fine.

  }

});

return newfilename;
//thisreturnsnothing, however if I change it to return 'Whatever'; it does return Whatever.
}
```

Comment: you created newfilename again in success block, try to change it from `var newfilename = json['filename']` to `newfilename=json['filename']`

Comment: Yeah I get something when I alert that.  Yeah I understand the async stuff.  Have done a bunch of research and I just can't figure out how to return what I need when I call that setup_file function.  I have tried other solutions, but they just seem to set the variable to be used rather than returning it as I am needing to.

Comment: have you tried with removing the `var` for `newfilename` in success block?

Comment: AHHH!  Such a stupid mistake.  Thank you so much.   Appears to be working.  Happy to vote this up if you want to answer it or delete it as there is probably a duplicate out there.  You tell me.

Comment: Happy to help. Please upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created, same variable again in the success block, that cause the outer variable empty. Change the

```
var newfilename = json['filename'];
```

to

```
newfilename=json['filename']
```

In the success block.